extract strings between square brackets and arrange them as csv
I need to remove the brackets around the strings from multiple lines of output and print them as csv.
This is what I tried.
#!/bin/bash

input_string="Group [BO_analytics_Corp] in security domain [Native]: [+r+w].
Group [Tooling_Ops] in security domain [Met_LDAP]: [+r+w].
Group [Gov_tools] in security domain [Met_LDAP]: [+r+w+g]."

echo $(echo $input_string | grep -oP '(?<=\[).*?(?=\])' | tr '\n' ',')

This is what I am expecting.
BO_analytics_Corp,Native,+r+w
Tooling_Ops,Met_LDAP,+r+w
Gov_tools,Met_LDAP,+r+w+g

But this is what I am getting when I run the script.
BO_analytics_Corp,Native,+r+w,Tooling_Ops,Met_LDAP,+r+w,Gov_tools,Met_LDAP,+r+w+g,


You're replacing all newlines with ,. How do you expect to get multiple lines of output?

I tried removing the , with a new line but still it is putting the output in one line.

If you removed tr '\n' ',' then the output won't all be on one line.

Here's a very simple approach using awk. It uses brackets as field delimiter, and prints the second, fourth, and sixth column.
awk -F '[][]' -v OFS=, '{print $2,$4,$6}' <<< "$input_string"

If the number of fields is unknown, here's an alternative, yet still simple approach using GNU Awk's FPAT with a regex defining a field's pattern, and a loop to iterate over all fields:
gawk -v FPAT='\\[[^]]*\\]' -v OFS=, '{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = substr($i, 2, length($i)-2); print;
}' <<< "$input_string"

Output:
BO_analytics_Corp,Native,+r+w
Tooling_Ops,Met_LDAP,+r+w
Gov_tools,Met_LDAP,+r+w+g


General approach:

find strings between pairs of brackets ([string])
print said strings plus a trailing comma (,)
strip off last/trailing comma

Modifying OP's sample input to include a line with 4 bracketed strings:
input_string="Group [BO_analytics_Corp] in security domain [Native]: [+r+w].
Group [Tooling_Ops] in security domain [Met_LDAP]: [+r+w].
Group [Gov_tools] in security domain [Met_LDAP]: [+r+w+g].
Group [More_stuff] in security domain [Met_LDAP]: [+r+w+g] and one [extra string]."

One sed approach:
sed -E 's/[^[]*\[([^]]*)][^[]*/\1,/g; s/,$//' <<< "$input_string"

Where:

"$input_string" - wrap variable reference in double quotes in order to maintain the embedded linefeeds; without the double quotes the linefeeds will be converted to single spaces and the entire set of data will be processed as a single line of data
<<< "$input_string" - feed to sed as a here-string; eliminates unnecessary use of echo as well as the extra subshell required for the pipe operation
-E - enable extended regex support
brackets ([]) have special meaning to sed so to treat as literal characters we need to bracket/escape them
[^[]*\[ - match zero or more characters that are not a literal [ followed by a literal [
([^]]*) - (1st capture group) match zero or more characters that are not a a literal ]
][^[]* - match a literal ] followed by zero or more characters that are not a literal [
\1, - replace the overall match with the contents of the 1st capture group and append a comma
g - 'g'lobal match and replace (ie, as many times as found on the input line)
at this point we have something that looks like string1,string2,...,stringN,; everything we want except for the trailing comma so ...
s/,$// - remove the trailing comma

This generates:
BO_analytics_Corp,Native,+r+w
Tooling_Ops,Met_LDAP,+r+w
Gov_tools,Met_LDAP,+r+w+g
More_stuff,Met_LDAP,+r+w+g,extra string


Personally, I'd use awk.
A variation on pmf's 1st answer to support an unknown number of bracketed strings ...
awk -F '[][]' '
{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) 
      printf "%s%s", (i==2 ? "" : ","), $i
  print ""
}' <<< "$input_string"

#### or as a one-liner:

awk -F '[][]' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s", (i==2 ? "" : ","), $i; print ""}' <<< "$input_string"

This generates:
BO_analytics_Corp,Native,+r+w
Tooling_Ops,Met_LDAP,+r+w
Gov_tools,Met_LDAP,+r+w+g
More_stuff,Met_LDAP,+r+w+g,extra string

